# Root access on Genymotion devices

Tags: root-access, genymotion

How to grant root access in Genymotion devices which doesn't have `Superuser` application?

In Nexus9 API 23 and S8 API 24 I have no `Superuser`, and so I couldn't provide root access to my application.

the result of `whoami` command for both of them is `root`.

more information: Host is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please see this: [Rooted Genymotion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705949/rooted-genymotion)

Comment: I check the link, but the solution doesn't work for me, I have no allow root access in developer options.